# What's most important in a power supply for a video workstation build? Input voltage, amperage, efficiency, or # of SATA connectors?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, raid

This is a practice question for the CompTIA A+ exam. I understand from reading other posts that some have strong opinions on this cert, but I'd just like to know *why* one answer is correct. I've thought about it and can't wrap my head around it.

**Summary**: You work as a computer technician for a production company that travels worldwide while filming and editing music videos. Due to the nature of video editing, you will be building a video production workstation for the company that will have the maximum amount of RAM, an 8-core CPU, a dedicated GPU, and a redundant array of solid-state devices for storage. You are now determining which power supply to install in the system. What is the MOST important characteristic to consider when choosing a power supply?

A) Input Voltage

B) Amperage of 12V Rail

C) Number of SATA connectors

D) Efficiency Rate

This is my thought process:

A) Input Voltage; This is based on where you live; In the  US we use 120V and in Europe they use 220-240. Most PSUs can support a wide range;Not really the most important consideration in my view.

B) Amperage of 12V Rail: The 12V rail is what powers high-performance components like the CPU. A high-performance CPU (Like the 8-core CPU mentioned), a dedicated graphics card (like the one mentioned) and RAID are going to need more power, so.. this may be correct.

C) Number of SATA connectors depends on the make/model of the PSU and the wattage. Higher wattage PSUs will generally come with more SATA connectors since they're designed for more complex systems like numerous drives. This can also be correct, since there's mention of RAID - thus indicating multiple drives, at least 2. If you purchase a PSU with x SATA connectors but you have y drives, you have to either make changes to your storage or buy a new PSU.

- I assume modular PSUs come into question here but, because there's no mention of it in the context, I won't consider it.

D) Efficiency rate, I would say, is primarily driven by budget and energy consumption needs. In the question provided, there's no particular mention of cost, so in my view this wouldn't be included.

Thus, at the end of my thought process I've eliminated A & D, and am left with B, or C. **But...which is *most* important? And why? Isn't that entirely subjective, so there's no actual answer unless there is complete context? Or am I completely missing something here?**

Comment: I think even mediocre PSU comes with like at least 4 - 6 SATA power connector? I subjectively vote for B, heh. (Also, having many connector does not necessarily mean that they can all be used simultaneously?)

Comment: @TomYan If this is correct, then I would agree with B. I'm still new to this, I've come across a few budget PSUs and they all came with 2, but the RAID make me consider that they would need 2+, but, in hindsight I think I did overlook this. If the number of SATA connectors is irrelevant due to most coming with 2-6 as a default, the most important is Amperage of 12V Rail. Thank you Tom!

Comment: This isn't a bad question, and your thoughts on this are good, but it would be better served on a discussion board or forum where discussion and back and forth are the primary goals, than it is here, where we try to provide specific answers to clear and practical questions.